# Check if directive has an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

and I want to evaluate the following trenary inside it:

```
{{ $scope.my-option ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}
```

like this:

```
<my-directive my-option></my-directive>
```

How can I do this? It should evaluate to true once I have the attribute, right? I've already binded the attribute with the `=` sign.

Comment: check it in link function of directive :link: function(scope, elem, attr) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't check for `$scope.my-option` here, but for `$scope.myOption`.

**CamelCased attributes are only snake-cased in HTML code**; they should be referenced using camelCase in all remaining JavaScript source.

So, your HTML tag should be like:

```
<my-directive my-option></my-directive>
```

But your AngularJS expression would be:

```
{{ $scope.myOption ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}
```

The `$scope` may not even be needed, what would reduce the expression to

```
{{ myOption ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}
```

---

Additionally, if you don't want to explicitly add the check as a watcher in your HTML, you may use the link function of your directive to do that. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) explains it in more detail.

In your directive, use it like the following snippet:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myOption: '=?'
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                if (scope.myOption) {
                    // you have the attribute
                } else {
                    // you don't
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `myOption: '=?'` is better

Answer (score 1):

In the case you don't have an isolated scope (and also works with isolated scope) you can check the attrs directly:

```
angular
.module('myModule')
.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var option;
            if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('myOption')) {
                // if attr is plain string
                option = attrs.myOption;
                // or parse from a scope property
                option = $parse(attrs.myOption)(scope);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain the last line `option = $parse(attrs.myOption)(scope);`. Please quote the technical terms used for it as well for us to google more

Comment: The $parse service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) is used to parse angular expressions. In this case it is only the name of a scope property which is given by the "my-option" attribute of the directive. $parse returns a function and first argument is the context, here our scope, on which the expression is evaluated. In simple words: It's getting the value of the scope property (variable) named as set by the my-options attribute. One could also write: `scope[attrs.myOption]`

Comment: okay. somewhat similar to `$compile`. Will read the differences